# Convert list of IOB formatted data to simple IOB formatted data

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, format

I am a beginner in nlp and want to generate IOB format from the list of sentences.

I have data in IOB format in the pattern below:

```py
[('in', 'O'), ('this', 'B-DATE'), ('week', 'I-DATE'), ('how', 'O'), ('many', 'O'), ('activities', 'O'), ('do', 'O'), ('i', 'O'), ('have', 'O'), ('?', 'O')]
```

The expected output is

```
in O
this B-DATE
week I-DATE
how O
many O
activities O
do O
i O
have O
? O
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a new `list` containing only strings composed from initial list's members, you can try something like this:

```py
initial = [('in', 'O'), ('this', 'B-DATE'), ('week', 'I-DATE'), ('how', 'O'), ('many', 'O'), ('activities', 'O'), ('do', 'O'), ('i', 'O'), ('have', 'O'), ('?', 'O')]

modified = [' '.join(z) for z in initial]

for row in modified:
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
in O
this B-DATE
week I-DATE
how O
many O
activities O
do O
i O
have O
? O
```