# spaCy How to initialize a Doc with entities in IOB format?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, spacy-3

In my spaCy project, I would like to initialize a Doc object with text, labels and whitespaces.
spaCy doesn't appreciate the way I provide the labels however, and shows its lack of appreciation in the following error message:

> ```
> doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=token_texts, ents=labels, spaces=whitespaces)
>   File "spacy\tokens\doc.pyx", line 297, in spacy.tokens.doc.Doc.__init__
> ValueError: [E177] Ill-formed IOB input detected: ('', 'O')
> ```

The code:

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

token_texts = ["I", "like", "potatoes", "!"]
labels = [("", "O"), ("", "O"), ("food", "I"), ("", "O")]
whitespaces = [True, True, False, False]
doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=token_texts, ents=labels, spaces=whitespaces)
```

**Does anyone know how to exactly serve spaCy the entities on the silver platter?**

The [spaCy Doc documentation](https://spacy.io/api/doc) states

> ents:
> A list of strings, of the same length of words, to assign the
> token-based IOB tag. Defaults to None. Optional[List[str]]

The type-hint `List[str]` made me attempt `["", "", "food", ""]`, which however results in the same error message.

Stackoverflow links that do not have the answer:

[Convert NER SpaCy format to IOB format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59730960/convert-ner-spacy-format-to-iob-format)

[Convert list of IOB formatted data to simple IOB formatted data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56774812/convert-list-of-iob-formatted-data-to-simple-iob-formatted-data)

[Failed to convert iob to spaCy binary format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69405517/failed-to-convert-iob-to-spacy-binary-format)

[Replace to entity tags to IOB format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69044909/replace-to-entity-tags-to-iob-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOB tags should be in the same format used in CoNLL files, so like "B-PERSON". So in your example code:

```
labels = ["O", "O", "I-FOOD", "O"]
```